# How can you deduce $|a – b| \geq ||a| – |b||$ from $|a + b| \leq |a| + |b|$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I tried but I couldn't. Can you try and explain me?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{a-b} + \mathbb b = \mathbb a$

Answer (score 5):

By the triangle inequality,
$$
|a|=|a-b+b|\le|a-b|+|b|
$$
and
$$
|b|=|b-a+a|\le|b-a|+|a|
$$
so that
$$
||a|-|b||\le|a-b|.
$$
It is called the [reverse triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).